# rank multiple subsets of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rank a dataframe in two parts.  First by getting subset where A and B are True and ranking those values, and then getting the remaining values and ranking those.

Input:

```
       A      B       C

1    False   True    23 
2    True    True    44
3    True    True    10
4    True    False    9
```

Output:

```
       A      B       C   rank

1    False   True    23     4
2    True    True    44     2
3    True    True    10     1
4    True    False    9     3
```

I can't seem to do this without making copies of the dataframes and merging results back together. But I assume I should be able to do this in a simple step

Comment: How do you want duplicate C values to be handled?

Comment: @DSM they should have the same rank

Answer (score 0):

This is my Suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[False,True,33],[True,True,44],[True,True,10],[True,False,9],[True,True,44]],columns=['A','B','C'])

df['TT'] = [1 if a&b else 0 for a,b in zip(df.A,df.B)]  #1 means both True

df.sort_values(['TT','C'],ascending=[False,True],inplace=True)

n = 1  
rank = []
for i,group in df.groupby(['TT','C'],sort=False):   #by default groupby sorts ascendingly so prevent sorting
    for i1 in group.index:
        rank.append(n)
    n+=1

df['Rank'] = rank

df.sort_index()
```